# Чтение EditText из других activity

Tags: android

есть EditText он находится на активити1, нужно чтобы текст с него ещё отображался на активити2 и активити3
А также на активити2 есть кнопка которая должна написать что-то и это должно отображаться на всех активити(активити1,активити2активити3) то есть должно передаться на активити1

mainActivity1.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="408dp"
    android:layout_height="126dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:editable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="auto"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    tools:ignore="Deprecated,MissingConstraints"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="108.0dip"
    android:layout_height="105.0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="353dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@color/white"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

mainActivity1.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
ImageButton next;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    next =findViewById(R.id.next);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.append("text 1 \n");
        }}, 970);

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.append("text 2 \n");
                }}, 16500);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.append("text 3 \n");
                }}, 17500);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 18000);
        }};
    handler.postDelayed(r1, 1);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }
    });
}}
```

mainActivity2.xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="auto"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:ignore="Deprecated,MissingConstraints"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="108.0dip"
        android:layout_height="105.0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="248dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@color/black"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="544dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="122dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@color/black"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

mainActivity2.java:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView textView;
    ImageButton ImageButton;
    ImageButton back;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        ImageButton=findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        back=findViewById(R.id.back);
        ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView.append("text ?? \n");
                    }});
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity2.this.finish();
                   }});
    }}
```

Comment: сохраните в отдельный класс и вытаскивайте оттуда потом, как по мне более логично чем использовать SharedPreferences

Comment: @Andrew, не могли бы помочь с кодом, я не знаю как сохраните в отдельный класс , а SharedPreferences ещё сложнее

Comment: вот пример можно отсюда взять - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-singleton-class-in-android, там все более-менее нормально описано

Comment: @Andrew, вроде всё получилось, но появилась одна проблема цветной текст не переносится

Comment: ну слушайте)))) цветной текст вы не сохраните :D это ж UI, просто после установки текста ставьте цвет, НО если нужно сохранить цвет в памяти также как и строку, то это опять таки можно сделать при помощи SP